# How to use method results from one class in another

Tags: python, class

Im just learning about classes in python and I would
like to know how results from a method in one class can
be used in a another class..here is the scenario.

```
Class A:

    def x(self):
        #do stuff and call Class B

Class B:
    def y(self):
        #do stuff get results and pass results to Class A
        results
```

How can results be passed back to Class A ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you want this

```
class A:

    def x(self):
        #do stuff and call Class B
        n = 1
        n += B().y() #Instance B and call y method
        print n

class B:
    def y(self):
        #do stuff get results and pass results to Class A
        x = 10
        return x

a = A() #create a object with type A
a.x() #call x method of A class
```

Comment: Thank You all, no I know where to start..@cyber , @ashalynd

Comment: @mikie so, did you get it? what else can we do for you? I noticed you have not accepted any answer

Answer (score 1):

```
Class A:
    def x(self):
        #do stuff and call Class B
        my_B = B()
        theResult = my_B.y()    # you just called B's function y()

Class B:
    def y(self):
        #do stuff get results and pass results to Class A
        return results
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you create class B within the method A.x:

```
Class A:

    def x(self):
        #do stuff and call Class B
        results = B().y()

Class B:
    def y(self):
        #do stuff get results and pass results to Class A
        return results
```

Assuming method A.x gets the object of class B:

```
Class A:

    def x(self, b):
        #do stuff and call Class B
        results = b.y()

Class B:
    def y(self):
        #do stuff get results and pass results to Class A
        return results
```